# jQuery animate not working on $(this)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate a bunch of `<div>`'s with `.animate` with this function:

```
slideOut: function(container){
    var count = container.siblings().size() - 1;
    container.siblings().each(function(index, item){
        $(item).delay( index * 50 ).animate({ "left" : "-1000px" }, "fast", function(){
            if (index == count){
                container.delay(container.parent().parent().children().size() > 10 ? 10 * 50 + 300 : container.parent().parent().children().size() * 50 + 300  ).animate({ "left":"-1000px" }, "fast", function(){
                    container.parent().parent().clone(true, true).appendTo(metro.tiles);
                    metro.overlay(container.parent().parent().parent());
                }); 
            }       
        });
    });

},
```

and I am using the following function to bring them back in to the DOM:

```
slideInTiles: function(){
    $("#contentWrapper").empty();
    $("#contentWrapper").append(metro.tiles.children());

    $("#contentWrapper li").animate({"left": "0px"}, "fast");
    $("#contentWrapper li.activeTile").css({"left": "0px"}, "fast");
},
```

The problem, however, is that the `<li>` I click on does not get animated back in to the mix. I have to use `.css` to bring it back. Where is the bug in the code that is causing this problem? Also, since I am bringing the active `li` back by using `.css` it no longer animates out of the view either. I am pretty sure this has got to do with the `.clone` method. But how, I can't figure.

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: You mention `$(this)` in your title but I don't see any such thing in your code.

Comment: this is just small part of the app. creating a demo would be very tough. if u need any clarifications, please let me know.

Comment: If you can't [construct a self-contained demo](http://sscce.org), then you might be asking in the wrong place.

Comment: why are you emptying contentWrapper? when you empty it, those li elements are removed, so when you append the new one, they aren't going to have a css of left:-1000px

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without a proper example or some more relevant code but I'd say your problem is probably here:

```
container.delay(container.parent().parent().children().size() > 10 ? 10 * 50 + 300 : container.parent().parent().children().size() * 50 + 300).animate({
```

`delay()` only works on a queue and you're using it before starting any queue. Then, there must be a better selector than `container.parent().parent().children().size()`...
Also, you might want to use `length` instead of `size()`. `size()` is just a shortcut that returns the `length`. Finally, I would cache all those selectors so your app can perform a bit faster, ie. `$("#contentWrapper")` can be cached.

Comment: By caching I mean that you assign your selector(s) to a variable that way jQuery won't have to look for your elements all the time. ie `var $wrapper = $("#contentWrapper")` and then you use it like `$wrapper.doSomething()`

Answer (score 0):

firstly, I would recommend to take a step back and simplify from where you are and go step by step, so you know when your problem begins. take a look at this fiddle which shows problems can stem from using pixels, and you should use percent instead: http://jsfiddle.net/UVPYW/1/ beyond that, make sure you pay attention to @elclanrs answer about the delay, but also make sure that you are not removing or cloning the original element which you want to wisk off the screen. it looks like in your code that you actually remove the element inside #contentWrapper which was animated in the first place, which will cause a problem when you try and animate it back on.  if you want to animate a NEW element on screen, make sure you set in the css it to have the negative value first. so set it to have a left of -1000 originally and when you animate, make sure it goes to the left value which is visible on your screen